# Limit GET requests (D3.js/Twitter API)

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, twitter, get

I am currently using D3.js and have modified my chart from listening to mouseover/mouseout to mousemove. This has brought quite a few issues in the chart but none moreso than my `GET statuses/show/:id` requests.

Previously, I would have points on my chart to hover over and if there was a tweet within half an hour of that point (from a tweet DB in backend), it would send a GET request to get that tweet.

My problem now is that because I'm using mousemove in proximity to these points on my chart as opposed to mouseover, its firing this hundreds of times and the GET requests are limited to 900 in a 15-minute window.

```
var tweet_arr = [];
for(j in data_tweets){
    var tweet_time = timeParser(data_tweets[j]['timestamp_s']);
    var point_time = timeParser(d.timestamp);
    var diff = point_time.getTime() - tweet_time.getTime();
    if(diff<=1800000 && diff>=-1800000) {
        tweet_arr.push(data_tweets[j]);
    } else {
        var tweet_list = []
        d3.selectAll(".panel-body")
            .data(tweet_list)
            .exit()
            .remove();
    }
}
twitterapi.fetch().getTweets(tweet_arr, tweet_urls[0], tweet_urls[1]);
```

This function checks the difference between the nearest point on the x-axis and checks my collection of tweet data, if there is one in half an hour, add it to an array called `tweet_arr` and then pass that into my `fetch()` function which has an AJAX call to the Flask framework where I run my GET request by ID.

What I would ideally want it to do is have some check that if the request to fetch a specific tweet has been carried out in say, the last 5 seconds, don't run the `fetch()` function.

How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: **UPDATE:** I've tried using underscore.js's debounce function, with even a second in delay but it still seems to fire far more frequently than that. `var lazyFetch = _.debounce(function(){twitterapi.fetch().getTweets(tweet_arr, tweet_urls[0], tweet_urls[1])}, 1000); lazyFetch()`

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at debounce and throttle from underscore.js: http://underscorejs.org/#debounce, 
http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Here's a good, short post about debouncing requests: https://www.google.de/amp/s/davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function/amp

For a comparison between throttle and debounce, see https://gist.github.com/makenova/7885923

You need to define your fetch logic in a separate function and put that one into `_.debounce`.

Have a look at this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQwzpZ?editors=0011

```
const fetchFromTwitter = function(s) { console.log(s) }
var lazyFetch = _.debounce(fetchFromTwitter, 100)

lazyFetch('This is')
lazyFetch('is')
lazyFetch('gonna be')
lazyFetch('legen ... ')
lazyFetch('wait for it')
lazyFetch('... dary')
lazyFetch('LEGENDARY')
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that would work and I did try that but it still seems to fire constantly, I'm not sure what's wrong. (I added the code I used for debouncing in the comment above).

Comment: Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/dcorb/embed/YwNwRX?height=400&theme-id=light&default-tab=result&embed-version=2